# how to skip switchIfEmpty (avoid Mono<Optional>) if flatMap returns Mono<Void>

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm implementing a GatewayFilter, which checks the cached result first before contacting HTTP API.

```
@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
    // loadFromCache may return Mono.emtpy if no cached result found
    return loadFromCache(exchange.getRequest().getPath().toString())
            .flatMap(s -> {
                // if cached value exists, return directly
                ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
                Flux<DataBuffer> cached = Flux.just(response.bufferFactory().wrap(s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
                return response.writeWith(cached);
            }).switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> {
                // if no cached value found, calling http api to get a response
                return chain.filter(exchange);
            }));
}
```

The problem is `switchIfEmpty` also works on `Mono<Void>` returned from `flatMap` operation. One solution is to `map` the value from `loadFromCache` to `Optional<String>`, then do `ifPresent` check in `flatMap`. This seems unnecessary to me. Is there any other solution without using `Optional`? Thanks!

Comment: The only way to do it is to differentiate return “empty” value from  `loadFromCache` from `Mono.empty()` and your solution with `Optional` would work. 
But in general there is nothing wrong with calling `chain.filter(exchange)` because it’s NOOP operation. 
In addition you  don’t really need `Mono.defer` there

Comment: @Alex Yes, I suppose the special empty value is inevitable. Thanks for mentioning the `Mono.defer` part, I checked `DefaultGatewayFilterChain#filter` and it already has a `Mono.defer` there.